# Modular Arithmetic - Proof using Wilson's Theorem

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Q. Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that $1^2\cdot2^2\cdot3^2\cdots(p-1)^2-1$ is divisble by $p$.

Please let me know if my proof makes sense.

Attempt:

Proof: Wilson's Theorem:

$(p-1)!+1\equiv 0  \pmod p$

$(p-1)!\equiv -1  \pmod p$

$(p-1)!^2\equiv (-1)^2  \pmod p$

$(p-1)!^2\equiv 1  \pmod p$

$(p-1)!^2 -1\equiv 0  \pmod p$

Hence, $1^2\cdot2^2\cdot3^2\cdots(p-1)^2-1$ is divisble by $p$.

Comment: Its good... .... !!

Comment: You can prove this without invoking Wilson...

Comment: How do you prove this without invoking Wilson's? Out of curiosity.